# Symfony Distinct On date_trunc

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

Hi i have a problem i want use symfony doctrine  for my request in native SQL it works but i want make it in doctrine. I use symfony4

I have create custom DQL date_trunc and register

What i want to  do is that :

```
DISTINCT ON (date,ipp.link) date_trunc('day', ip.date) AS date
```

I have try this one

```
$qb->select("i,COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(date,ipp.link)  date_trunc('day',ip.date) as date) AS maxScore");
```

but not work

say :

```
 "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 31: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'date'"}
```

When i test without CONCAT just `DISTINCT(date,ipp.link)` i got this:

```
Expected Doc…ine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','"}
```

I think problem is cause on native it s DISTINCT ON and here it s DISTINCT CONCAT but don t know how do that in doctrine

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mentioned that you have the query working in native SQL: please edit your question to include it, to give us a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have write here :   DISTINCT ON (date,ipp.link) date_trunc('day', ip.date) AS date